# Chrome Extension paste a text template

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to to have a context menu that allows the user to select from a couple different templates and paste it to a text box. I have the context menu populating the correct names for the templates, the only thing I'm missing is the placing the text to the desired field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to answer this is to point you to an extension that is already doing what you want....
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abmgjcmmphkhndoahbfanhbgeekconmm?hl=en-US
...have a look at its content.js file to see what their doing.

Comment: For any other neophytes that don't want to waste 10 minutes searching, you can find this file after installing the extension. On a mac (in my case OSX 10.7.5 and chrome 36.0.*) this can be found in: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/{uuid-of-the-extension}/js/`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comment listing where the extensions can be found at for MAC's, for Windows PC (Vista+) they can be found at

```
SYSTEMDRIVE(C:)\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\{uuid-of-the-extension}\js
```